# Is this the correct way to show a finite field is not ordered?

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, field-theory, ordered-fields

*I know there are similar questions asked but but I want to know if it works the way I wrote it.

We are given the set $\Bbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$ , the binary digits with arithmetic modulo 2. That is the usual set of rules we are accustomed to with the exception $1+1=1$

Proof by contradiction,

Let us suppose $\Bbb Z_2$ is an ordered field, then, we know, if $\Bbb F$ is an ordered field and $a,b,c \in \Bbb F$

$a<b \iff a+c<b+c$

Since $a<b$ we get, $a=0$ and $b=1$

For $c$ there can be two cases:

When $c=0$, we have $0+0<1+0 \implies 0 \lt1$

When $c=1$, we have $0+1<1+1 \implies  1\lt0$

Since $1\lt0$ is a contradiction, it follows that $Z_2$ is not an ordered field

Comment: Actually, it's $1+1=\color{red}0$.

Comment: Assuming you take what JoséCarlosSantos says on board, then you can use this methodology to prove every field of nonzero characteristic (regardless of if finite) cannot be ordered

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's my mistake. I did it correctly in the proof below.

Comment: Asides from the mistake in writing my questions, does the proof hold?

Comment: The idea works, and it is (more or less) the same if you apply it to any Field with characteristic $\noteq$ 0. Indeed, the 2 cases you showed actually help you in generalizing the procedure.